# SharePoint 2013 restrict usage of Share Point App

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have deployed a SharePoint-hosted application and it is currently visible to anyone who can authenticate to the Share Point site. How can the access/visibility be restricted to just a certain user group?

Comment: Did you get some solution on restrict apps visibility?.. If yes, please share, i am facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint hosted app can be installed in two scopes . Tenancy scope and sitecollection. 
For making the app visible to only specific users u have to opt for Tenancy scope.
Go to the app catalogue in central admin.

Go to the app catalogue of the webapplication in which the developer site is hosted and install the app there . while installing u get the option of making it visible to a set of people sitecollections and some other options

Comment: More details - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179896(v=office.15).aspx#AppScope